# Resampling with custom periods

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a 'cookbook' way of resampling a DataFrame with (semi)irregular periods?

I have a dataset at a daily interval and want it to resample to what sometimes (in scientific literature) is named dekad's. I dont think there is a proper English term for it but its basically chopping a month in three ~ten-day parts where the third is a remainder of anything between 8 and 11 days.

I came up with two solutions myself, a specific one for this case and a more general one for any irregular periods. But both arent really good, so im curiuous how others handle these type of situations.

Lets start with creating some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

begin = pd.datetime(2013,1,1)
end = pd.datetime(2013,2,20)

dtrange = pd.date_range(begin, end)

p1 = np.random.rand(len(dtrange)) + 5
p2 = np.random.rand(len(dtrange)) + 10

df = pd.DataFrame({'p1': p1, 'p2': p2}, index=dtrange)
```

The first thing i came up with is grouping by individual months (YYYYMM) and then slicing it manually. Like:

```
def to_dec1(data, func):

    # create the indexes, start of the ~10day period
    idx1 = pd.datetime(data.index[0].year, data.index[0].month, 1)
    idx2 = idx1 + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
    idx3 = idx2 + datetime.timedelta(days=10)

    # slice the period and perform function
    oneday = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    fir = func(data.ix[:idx2 - oneday].values, axis=0)
    sec = func(data.ix[idx2:idx3 - oneday].values, axis=0)
    thi = func(data.ix[idx3:].values, axis=0)

    return pd.DataFrame([fir,sec,thi], index=[idx1,idx2,idx3], columns=data.columns)

dfmean = df.groupby(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m'), group_keys=False).apply(to_dec1, np.mean)
```

Which results in:

```
print dfmean

                  p1         p2
2013-01-01  5.436778  10.409845
2013-01-11  5.534509  10.482231
2013-01-21  5.449058  10.454777
2013-02-01  5.685700  10.422697
2013-02-11  5.578137  10.532180
2013-02-21       NaN        NaN
```

Note that you always get a full month of 'dekads' in return, its not a problem and easy to remove if needed.

The other solution works by providing a range of dates at which you chop up the DataFrame and perform a function on each segment. Its more flexible in terms of the periods you want.

```
def to_dec2(data, dts, func):

    chucks = []
    for n,start in enumerate(dts[:-1]):

        end = dts[n+1] - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        chucks.append(func(data.ix[start:end].values, axis=0))

    return pd.DataFrame(chucks, index=dts[:-1], columns=data.columns)

dfmean2 = to_dec2(df, dfmean.index, np.mean)
```

Note that im using the index of the previous result as the range of dates to save some time 'building' it myself.

What would be the best way of handling these cases? Is there perhaps a bit more build-in method in Pandas?

Comment: for the more general case, you could groupby on a multi-index of [date,num_of_days],  (your routine could easily populate these groups wherever your want them), then groupby like normal. There is probably a more efficient way to do this with TimeGrouper in any event (but I have to think about it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use numpy 1.7, you can use datetime64 & timedelta64 arrays to do the calculation:

create the sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

begin = pd.datetime(2013,1,1)
end = pd.datetime(2013,2,20)

dtrange = pd.date_range(begin, end)

p1 = np.random.rand(len(dtrange)) + 5
p2 = np.random.rand(len(dtrange)) + 10

df = pd.DataFrame({'p1': p1, 'p2': p2}, index=dtrange)
```

calculate the dekad's date:

```
d = df.index.day - np.clip((df.index.day-1) // 10, 0, 2)*10 - 1
date = df.index.values - np.array(d, dtype="timedelta64[D]")
df.groupby(date).mean()
```

The output is:

```
                 p1         p2
2013-01-01  5.413795  10.445640
2013-01-11  5.516063  10.491339
2013-01-21  5.539676  10.528745
2013-02-01  5.783467  10.478001
2013-02-11  5.358787  10.579149
```

Answer (score 2):

Using HYRY's data and solution up to the computation of the `d` variable, we can also do the following in pandas 0.11-dev or later (regardless of numpy version):

```
In [18]: from datetime import timedelta

In [23]: pd.Series([ timedelta(int(i)) for i in d ])
Out[23]: 
0             00:00:00
1     1 days, 00:00:00
2     2 days, 00:00:00
3     3 days, 00:00:00
4     4 days, 00:00:00
5     5 days, 00:00:00
6     6 days, 00:00:00
7     7 days, 00:00:00
8     8 days, 00:00:00
9     9 days, 00:00:00
10            00:00:00

47    6 days, 00:00:00
48    7 days, 00:00:00
49    8 days, 00:00:00
50    9 days, 00:00:00
Length: 51, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

The date is constructed similary to above

```
date = pd.Series(df.index) - pd.Series([ timedelta(int(i)) for i in d ])
df.groupby(date.values).mean()
```

Comment: It doesnt in 10.1, im not running dev versions. Good to know for the future, thanks!