# Resample data pandas

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a large csv file which i am trying to resample.
i can manage to resample it by many timeframes like monthly, daily, quartely annually etc only that this time i want to use 1/10 of a year and then interpolate the value column.

check the example below of end product required.

```
name    year    value
eBay    2010    8342.7
eBay    2010.1  8453
eBay    2010.2  8588.2
eBay    2010.3  8723.4
eBay    2010.4  8858.6
eBay    2010.5  8993.8
eBay    2010.6  9129
eBay    2010.7  9264.2
eBay    2010.8  9399.4
eBay    2010.9  9534.6
eBay    2011    9669.8
eBay    2011.1  9805
eBay    2011.2  9919.2
eBay    2011.3  10033.4
```

Comment: Can you provide your starting data? This can get complicated given floating point precision

Comment: Similar but different question. You might find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408156/resampling-with-custom-periods)